# get all rows from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create an admin page wherein the admin can view all the data from the database, but my problem is whenever i try to select all the data it only return a single row, which is the first data with the id of 1.

Here is my php code:

```
$query_select = "SELECT `users_id`,`users_studno`,`users_fname`,`users_lname`,`users_email`,`users_password` FROM `tbl_usersinfo`";
        if($run_query = mysqli_query($con,$query_select))
        {
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
            {
                $id_val = htmlentities($row['users_id']);
                $studno_val = htmlentities($row['users_studno']);
                $fname_val = htmlentities($row['users_fname']);
                $lname_val = htmlentities($row['users_lname']);
                $email_val = htmlentities($row['users_email']);
                $password_val = htmlentities($row['users_password']);

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$id_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$studno_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$fname_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$lname_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$email_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$password_val."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

I want to output all the data from the database, but it only returns the first row.

Comment: You have to loop over your results refer to manual first before posting a question [*`mysqli_fetch_assoc`*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: That's right - you're only requesting one row. You need to loop your code to retrieve multiple

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `while` loop.

Try this:

```
$query_select = "SELECT `users_id`,`users_studno`,`users_fname`,`users_lname`,`users_email`,`users_password` FROM `tbl_usersinfo`";
        if($run_query = mysqli_query($con,$query_select))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
            {
                $id_val = htmlentities($row['users_id']);
                $studno_val = htmlentities($row['users_studno']);
                $fname_val = htmlentities($row['users_fname']);
                $lname_val = htmlentities($row['users_lname']);
                $email_val = htmlentities($row['users_email']);
                $password_val = htmlentities($row['users_password']);

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$id_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$studno_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$fname_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$lname_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$email_val."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$password_val."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: haha thanks bro, i didn't know that i put if statement instead of while loop